# Unusual CSS behavior in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a *Header* and a *Nav* component in my React.js application. Inside the *Header* component I have placed my logo and the *Nav* contains usual navigation links. Since both are separate components and I don't want to wrap them inside another semantic tag. I just want both to get displayed adjacent to each other. I set both of their display property to *inline-flex* along with certain width. The *Header* components occupies the place it should have while the *Nav* component get displayed in a peculiar way with a little space above it as if I have provided *margin-top* to it. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Here is my *Header* Component followed by *Nav* component *App* component and *index.css* code.

**Header.js**

```
import React from "react";
import logo from '../assets/Logo .svg';

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <header className="header">
            <img className="nav-logo" src={logo} alt="Little Lemon" />
        </header>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

**Nav.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Nav = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="nav">
            <ul className="nav-list">
                <li><a className="nav-item" href="#"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a className="nav-item" href="#"> About </a></li>
                <li><a className="nav-item" href="#"> Menu </a></li>
                <li><a className="nav-item" href="#"> Reservations </a></li>
                <li><a className="nav-item" href="#"> Order Online </a></li>
                <li><a className="nav-item" href="#"> Login </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Nav;
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Main from './components/Main';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <Nav />
            <Main />
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**index.css**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
     display: inline-flex;
     width: 30%;
     border: 2px solid red;
     padding: 10px;
}

.nav-logo{
}

.nav {
     display: inline-flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: left;
     width: 70%;
     padding: 10px;
     border: 2px solid gray;
     height: 64px;
}

.nav-list{
     display: flex;
}

.nav-list li{
     list-style: none;
}

.nav-item{
     padding: 6px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to set vertical-align: top;

Comment: I totally forgot about that. It worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the parent of those 2 items a flex container so that they're aligned at the top:

```css
#react {
    display: flex;
}
```

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <header className="header">
            <img className="nav-logo" src={'https://placehold.co/75'} alt="Little Lemon" />
        </header>
    );
}

const Nav = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="nav">
            <ul className="nav-list">
                <li><a className="nav-item" href="#"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a className="nav-item" href="#"> About </a></li>
                <li><a className="nav-item" href="#"> Menu </a></li>
                <li><a className="nav-item" href="#"> Reservations </a></li>
                <li><a className="nav-item" href="#"> Order Online </a></li>
                <li><a className="nav-item" href="#"> Login </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header />
            <Nav />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#react {
    display: flex;
}

.header {
     display: inline-flex;
     width: 30%;
     border: 2px solid red;
     padding: 10px;
}

.nav-logo{
}

.nav {
     display: inline-flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: left;
     width: 70%;
     padding: 10px;
     border: 2px solid gray;
     height: 64px;
}

.nav-list{
     display: flex;
}

.nav-list li{
     list-style: none;
}

.nav-item{
     padding: 6px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: So you are saying, I should set the display of <React.Fragment>  as flex, doing so will ruin the structure of the page. all the components will get displayed on a same line. What I wanted to know is where the extra space is coming from ? I know I can handle it by making them siblings inside any tag of my liking.

Comment: No, look at the snippet i share. You should set flex on the `react` div, aka, the parent of those 2 components. A fragment does not render anything. Press 'Run code snippet' please.

Comment: I did that, it didn't had any effect. I set vertical-align property of the nav tag to top and that solved my problem. Thanks to @Okba for reminding me that. Your answer is misleading please remove it.

Comment: What? Did you ran the snippet? It works, the space is gone... Dont be such a stubborn.

Comment: Yes I did ran it, there was no effect, nothing changed.

Comment: I did exactly what you have done، it didn't worked for me tho.

Answer (score -1):

Try to give maxHight and maxWidth to navLogo class

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
     display: inline-flex;
     width: 30%;
     border: 2px solid red;
     padding: 10px;
}

.nav-logo{
maxHeight:'15px'
*///////*
}

.nav {
     display: inline-flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: left;
     width: 70%;
     padding: 10px;
     border: 2px solid gray;
     height: 64px;
}

.nav-list{
     display: flex;
}

.nav-list li{
     list-style: none;
}

.nav-item{
     padding: 6px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #333333;
}
```